# Python3 Tensorflow CPU ONLY Segmentation fault

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, cpu

I have pip3 installed tensorflow CPU only
Python version: 3.5.2

OS:LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
Release: 6.8
Codename: Santiago

Install command: pip3 install tensorflow

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/local/lib:/grapps/hadoop/instantclient/instantclient_11_2:/usr/local/lib:/opt/glibc-2.14/lib

Python 3.5.2 (default, Mar 23 2017, 07:51:35)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import tensorflow
Segmentation fault

Also tried to import scipy,numpy and matplotlib before importing tensorflow as per suggestion seens in some other cases https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2034.

But nothing solved the issue.

Thanks for the advice

Abraham